# Div containing images takes more space than required

Tags: html, css, footer

I am creating a footer section, and for some reason the `div` inside a section is taking more width than required. How do I fix this?

This is how it looks:

[image]

This is my code:

```css
footer {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 4rem;
}

#footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#footer .container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  /* justify-content: center; */
  margin: 0 2rem;
}

#contact-handle {
  width: 400px;
}

#contact-handle img {
  width: 40%;
  position: relative;
  right: 0.5rem;
}

#footer h4 {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#footer p {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  text-align: left;
}

#footer i {
  color: grey;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

#footer .button {
  display: flex;
}

#footer .button img {
  width: 15%;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <section id="footer">
    <div id="contact-handle" class="container">
      <img src="images/logo.png" alt="">
      <h4>Contact</h4>
      <p>Address: XXX ABCDE Road, Street 32, Mumbai</p>
      <p>Phone: (+91) 01234 56789/(+01) 2222 365</p>
      <p>Hours: 10:00 - 18:00, Mon - Sat</p>
      <br>
      <h4>Follow Us</h4>
      <div class="social_media">
        <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i>
        <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>
        <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
        <i class="fa-brands fa-youtube"></i>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="About" class="container">
      <h4>About</h4>
      <br>
      <p>About Us</p>
      <p>Delivery Information</p>
      <p>Privacy Policy</p>
      <p>Terms & Conditions</p>
      <p>Conatct Us</p>
    </div>

    <div id="Account" class="container">
      <h4>My Account</h4>
      <br>
      <p>Sign In</p>
      <p>View Cart</p>
      <p>My Wishlist</p>
      <p>Track Order</p>
      <p>Help</p>
    </div>

    <div id="App_gateway" class="container">
      <h4>Install App</h4>
      <br>
      <div class="button box">
        <img src="images/Footer-img/app-store.png">
        <img src="images/Footer-img/google-play.png">
      </div>
  </section>
</footer>
```

Comment: Try setting `width: auto` on `#contact-handle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't explain what kind of result that you were after, but I assume you want all of the flex children to share the same width: Just add `flex-basis: 100%` to give the flex children the same "weight" when determining their lengths.

```css
footer {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 4rem;
}

#footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 2rem;
}

#footer .container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  /* justify-content: center; */
  /*margin: 0 2rem;*/
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

#contact-handle {
  width: 400px;
}

#contact-handle img {
  width: 40%;
  position: relative;
  right: 0.5rem;
}

#footer h4 {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#footer p {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  text-align: left;
}

#footer i {
  color: grey;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

#footer .button {
  display: flex;
}

#footer .button img {
  width: 15%;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <section id="footer">
    <div id="contact-handle" class="container">
      <img src="images/logo.png" alt="">
      <h4>Contact</h4>
      <p>Address: XXX ABCDE Road, Street 32, Mumbai</p>
      <p>Phone: (+91) 01234 56789/(+01) 2222 365</p>
      <p>Hours: 10:00 - 18:00, Mon - Sat</p>
      <br>
      <h4>Follow Us</h4>
      <div class="social_media">
        <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i>
        <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>
        <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
        <i class="fa-brands fa-youtube"></i>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="About" class="container">
      <h4>About</h4>
      <br>
      <p>About Us</p>
      <p>Delivery Information</p>
      <p>Privacy Policy</p>
      <p>Terms & Conditions</p>
      <p>Conatct Us</p>
    </div>

    <div id="Account" class="container">
      <h4>My Account</h4>
      <br>
      <p>Sign In</p>
      <p>View Cart</p>
      <p>My Wishlist</p>
      <p>Track Order</p>
      <p>Help</p>
    </div>

    <div id="App_gateway" class="container">
      <h4>Install App</h4>
      <br>
      <div class="button box">
        <img src="images/Footer-img/app-store.png">
        <img src="images/Footer-img/google-play.png">
      </div>
  </section>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
footer {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 4rem;
}

#footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

#footer .container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  /* justify-content: center; */
  margin: 0 1rem;
}

#contact-handle {
  width: 400px;
}

#contact-handle img {
  width: 40%;
  position: relative;
  right: 0.5rem;
}

#footer h4 {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#footer p {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  text-align: left;
}

#footer i {
  color: grey;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

#footer .button {
  display: flex;
}

#footer .button img {
  width: 15%;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <section id="footer">
    <div id="contact-handle" class="container">
      <img src="images/logo.png" alt="">
      <h4>Contact</h4>
      <p>Address: XXX ABCDE Road, Street 32, Mumbai</p>
      <p>Phone: (+91) 01234 56789/(+01) 2222 365</p>
      <p>Hours: 10:00 - 18:00, Mon - Sat</p>
      <br>
      <h4>Follow Us</h4>
      <div class="social_media">
        <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i>
        <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>
        <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
        <i class="fa-brands fa-youtube"></i>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="About" class="container">
      <h4>About</h4>
      <br>
      <p>About Us</p>
      <p>Delivery Information</p>
      <p>Privacy Policy</p>
      <p>Terms & Conditions</p>
      <p>Conatct Us</p>
    </div>

    <div id="Account" class="container">
      <h4>My Account</h4>
      <br>
      <p>Sign In</p>
      <p>View Cart</p>
      <p>My Wishlist</p>
      <p>Track Order</p>
      <p>Help</p>
    </div>

    <div id="App_gateway" class="container">
      <h4>Install App</h4>
      <br>
      <div class="button box">
        <img src="images/Footer-img/app-store.png">
        <img src="images/Footer-img/google-play.png">
      </div>
  </section>
</footer>
```

I just removed the `justify-content: space-between` from `#footer` and decreased the margin for this `#footer .container`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `display: flex;` in your `.container`.

You can set it to `display: relative;`and set a `min-width: 100px;` for example to align these items to exactly